# How to apply encoding in existing pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using python 3.x. I need to apply encoding in my pandas data frame which contains 2391653 rows & 35 columns. I need to apply endcoding only for name column. So I tried this code

```
df1=df.Name.str.encode('utf-8-sig')
```

But df1 is storing only name column. Can you please suggest me how to apply encoding only for 1 column & remaining columns will be unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently creating a new dataframe df1 with only the column 'Name' of df with the encoding applied.

You should try to create a new column in df instead:

df['New_Name'] = df.Name.str.encode('utf-8-sig')